# Exact Search, not partial

Tags: c#

thanks everyone for your help, it gave me many ideas, and show me a lot o ways of using diferent functions or methods... this is my fourth day with C#, learning in home, with tutorials... the answer to this was like that

procs[i].ProcessNmae... is not a frase... but a LIST...
so i did this

```
    public void chupala()
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < procs.Length; i++)
        {
            if (procs[i].ProcessName == "firefox")  //that way it search for the EXACT match...
            {
                using (var player = new SoundPlayer("C:\\bass.wav"))
                {
                    player.Play();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the public void chupala() is what i've created... the rest was downloaded, so it takes ALL running process... what i did is add that public void, so when I click the button IF firefox is open it will make a sound... the problem is that if a write "fire" it makes the sound too... i tested this WITH MY PROGRAM OPEN, close firefox... press the button... nothen happens... open firefox... click the button, the sound activates... but if i have another application that starts or contains the word fire it will make the sound anyway :s thats why i need it to find the EXACT match...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics; 
using System.Media;

namespace SimpleTaskManager
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Process[] procs;
        public void GetProcesses()
        {
            procs = Process.GetProcesses();
            if (Convert.ToInt32(label2.Text) != procs.Length) // Check if new processes have been started or terminated
            {
                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < procs.Length; i++)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(procs[i].ProcessName);  // Add the process name to the listbox
                }
                label2.Text = procs.Length.ToString();
            }
        }
        public void chupala()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < procs.Length; i++)
            {
                bool b;
                b = (procs[i].ProcessName.Contains("fire"));
                if (b)
                {
                    using (SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer("C:\\bass.wav"))
                    {
                        player.Play();
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetProcesses();
        }

        // Check every 1 second for changes in the processes list
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetProcesses();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chupala();
//            procs[listBox1.SelectedIndex].Kill(); // Kill the process coresponding to the selected index of listbox1 
        }

        private void kIllProcessToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            procs[listBox1.SelectedIndex].Kill();
        }

        public void lsit()
        {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Split the string into array of words using the `String.Split` method and find the desired word in that array.

Comment: let me post the original code, so you understand what i am trying to acomplish...

Comment: @user3471081 what are you trying to do, just play a sound when Firefox is closed? Why not just use the whole word "Firefox" then, instead of just "fire"?

Comment: Your question no longer makes sense. You want "Firefox" to match the word "fire" but not any other string that contains "fire"? How is "Firefox" an exact match for "fire"?

Comment: what i ment is that if i SEARCH using the word FIREFOX it finds FIREFOX... if i SEARCH using the word Fire... it finds FIREFOX (because Fire is PART of the word firefox...)

Comment: @user3471081 please avoid using all caps LIKE THIS, because it looks like you're yelling. You can make comments bold by using `**comment**` if you want, **like this**.

Comment: oh, sorry... didn't know... the caps where just to reise the importance of this particular words... no mean to disrespect u.u

Comment: you change the question most completely.

Comment: yes i did, but the answer was the same for the two questions... i wanted to acomplish the same thing in the same way... anyhow... i already rescover an answer... and i posted in the first part of the "question" post :p thanks to everyone for the support and the time spent...

Answer (score 4):

Another way you can do this is to use a [regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) to search, and putting your search term between word boundarys `\b`:

```
// Returns false
Regex.IsMatch("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", @"\bfo\b")

// Returns true
Regex.IsMatch("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", @"\bfox\b")
```

You can read more about word boundaries [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

> Simply put: `\b` allows you to perform a "whole words only" search using a regular expression in the form of `\bword\b`. A "word character" is a character that can be used to form words. All characters that are not "word characters" are "non-word characters".

#### Update because I got more info from original poster

Rewrite your `chupala()` method to use a `Regex` to do the search, instead of using the `Contains` method:

```
public void chupala()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < procs.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(procs[i].ProcessName, @"\bFirefox\b"))
        {
            using (var player = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\bass.wav"))
            {
                player.Play();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tryed that too.... no sound... the program is running... but does nothing more than show me ALL the process running (like it always did)... no sound

Comment: Have you tried displaying the strings for all the process names? Can you show them to us in your question?

Comment: https://scontent-a-iad.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/v/t1.0-9/p320x320/10149828_834189776597173_1476242271_n.jpg?oh=e963a64da1e0053d80532402655b0529&oe=5398E4BB

i did a print screen with the program running... is that one.. when i press in the button that says "end process" it should do a sound IF firefox is in the list... firefox is in the list...

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't even read that, it's too small.

Comment: anyway... i did it n.n you can try the project if you want to see what it does :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the fastest search, but here is what you can do

- Split your input string by delimiter (in your case this is SPACE - `s1.Split(" ")`)
- Iterate over the result array
- Check if `s2` equals to any of the items in the array

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
string s1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
string s2 = "fox";
bool b;
var words = s1.Split(' ');
foreach (var word in words)
{
    b = word.Equals(s2);
    if (b)
        break;
}
Console.WriteLine("Is the string, s2, in the string, s1?: {0}", b);
```

Comment: I've tryed the split thing... but it does ABSOLUTLY NOTHING... because... S1 is not JUST text... they are the name of the process of the Task Manager... dont know if it can "split" them... :S

Answer (score 0):

MSDN :

> The search begins at the first character position of this string and continues through the last character position.

This is a reason why you get the result **True**. if you want to search for exact string, you can **Regex**.

EDIT: I get an updated question

```
    public void chupala()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < procs.Length; i++)
        {
          bool b;

          // Use Regex in here, assume that ProcessName of Firefox app is Firefox
          b = Regex.IsMatch(procs[i].ProcessName, @"(^|\s)Firefox(/s|$)");

          if (b)
          {
                using (SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer("C:\\bass.wav"))
                {
                    player.Play();
                }

           }
        }
     }
```

Comment: use Regex.IsMatch where? instead of what?.... i dont get it...

Comment: the FINAL answer i need is a True or False (either the process IS or ISNT running... the "sound" i've added is just so i can test if it is working...

Comment: I get "Regex" does not exist in the current context

Comment: You should add namespace **System.Text.RegularExpression**

Comment: did that of the System.Text.RegularExpresion.... the application works again... but not sound is played... tryed using.... firefox Firefox Firefox.exe firefox.exe.... even try with "explorer" that is alway there... but no sound...

Comment: why don't you debug and the value of procs[i].ProcessName contains the name of Firefox application ?

Comment: it contains the name firefox... when i run the program it makes a list of the running applications in a text box... and firefox is on it... just firefox... without the .exe

Comment: FOUNDED THE ANSWER FOR MYSEEEELFFF!!! : D

Comment: @minhcat_vo the regex `(^|\s)Firefox(\s|$)` is actually equivalent to `\bFirefox\b`.